# Query oracle Db for data between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

Trying to query an oracle db table having date in format:  `2022-06-22T12:25:06.087` (`LocalDateTime.now().toString()`). Column type for created_time is varchar2.
Trying to query for data between two dates. I have tried the following but it results in error "date format not recognized":

```
select * from MY_TABLE
where to_date(created_time, 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS') 
between to_date('2022-07-03T10:15:06.091', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS') 
and to_date('2022-07-03T10:15:06.091', 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS');
```

Can anyone help me correct this query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format you used looks like data (in `CREATED_TIME` column) is stored as a timestamp. If that's so, you shouldn't *convert* it to another datatype (you chose `TO_DATE` function) but leave it *as is*. If you stored data as a string (that's usually a huge mistake), then apply the same `to_timestamp` function with the same format model as the one in `between` clause.

Apart from that, format model for minutes is `mi` (not `mm`; that's *month*), while fractional seconds is `ff3` (not `sss`).

```
SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE created_time 
   BETWEEN TO_TIMESTAMP ('2022-07-03T10:15:06.091', 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss.ff3')
       AND TO_TIMESTAMP ('2022-07-03T10:15:06.091', 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss.ff3');
```

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! Btw in my case data was stored as varchar2 (I know it was a bad idea) so I had to do TO_TIMESTAMP(created_time, 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss.ff3')

Comment: You're welcome; I'm glad you made it work.

Answer (score 2):

I guess column `created_time` is of data type `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP`. **Never** call `TO_DATE()` or `TO_TIMESTAMP()` to a values which is already a `DATE`

The `DATE` data type does not support fractional seconds, use `TIMESTAMP` instead. Format literals have to be enclosed by double quotes.

Format `HH` is the hour in 12-hour format. I assume you need 24-hour format, which is `HH24`. `mm` (or `MM`) is the Month, for Minute use `MI`. Format identifiers are not case-sensitive, so `SSS` is also wrong.

Try this one:

```
select * 
from MY_TABLE
where created_time
   between TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-07-03T10:15:06.091', 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:MI:ss.ff3') 
   and TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-07-03T10:15:06.091', 'yyyy-MM-dd"T"HH24:MI:ss.ff3');
```